Fantasy manga, not an Isekai (I think), about world of magic and monsters about a little boy who excels at magic
I am looking for a title about a little boy who was recently born and has an in-depth affinity for mysticism. In the first couple of chapters, we see him emulate the magic of a couple of individuals (his older sister, for one) and simulate it nearly perfectly. In an untranslated chapter, he's then seen replicating himself by three, each of his dupes using a different kind of magic. One of which expanded his left arm to disproportional sizes and had incredible strength.

There's a manga about a child reborn (I believe it is an isekai) with barrier magic; one of his feats using the barrier magic is to duplicate himself. I have no idea if any of the clones include the left arm detail, but does that sound like the same story?
